# Converting date formats in SQR

Tags: sql, oracle, date, type-conversion, sqr

I'm trying to convert an SQR string from the following format of `MM-DD-YYYY` into a format of `YYMMDD`.

I've tried to use the following SQR function:

`STRTODATE('03-09-2018', 'YYMMDD')` but I get the following error.

> (SQR 7501) Using YY edit mask from (YYMMDD) against (03-09-2018)
>
> (SQR 1914) Bad input data (12-01-2017) for edit mask: 'YYMMDD'

I think the problem is that the `STRTODATE` function is expecting the `YYMMDD` format, but the given format is in `MM-DD-YYYY`.

Is there another SQR function which I can use to convert the formats?

The only other approach I can think of is splitting the string into sub-strings and re-create the string, but I don't want it to become messy.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
Let $NewStr = STRTODATE('03-09-2018', 'YYMMDD')
```

Is there a specific SQR function which will do this for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're after this: `DATETOSTR(STRTODATE('03-09-2018', 'MM-DD-YYYY'), 'YYMMDD')`

1. You make a date from a `'MM-DD-YYYY'` string
2. You extract this date as a string with the format `'YYMMDD'`

[SQR DATE Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E41509_01/pt852pbh2/eng/psbooks/tsqr/chapter.htm?File=tsqr/htm/tsqr22.htm)

Comment: I oddly remember doing this in PL/SQL also.. should've remembered.. :|